# ¿Cómo puedo detener un bucle con setInterval() en JQuery en el mismo div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, animación, setinterval

Tengo que hacer una animación de un div que debe moverse a la izquierda y a la derecha continuamente, en este caso lo he hecho con un setInterval() para que me realice el bucle. Después tengo que parar la animación completamente clicando el mismo div con un .stop().
El problema es que la animación se detiene los segundos que le he puesto al setInterval() y vuelve a empezar la animación.
He intentado muchas cosas pero no me para del todo la animación.
Muchas gracias a todo.

```js
$("#movContinuo").click(function() {
  function empezarAnimacion() {
    $("#divTarget").animate({
        left: "+=200px"
      }, 2000)
      .animate({
        left: "-=200px"
      }, 2000);
  }
  setInterval(empezarAnimacion, 2000);
});

$("#movContinuo").click(function() {
  $("#divTarget").stop(true);
});
```

```css
#divTarget {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divTarget">
</div>
<button id="movContinuo">
Mover
</button>
```

Comment: Ademas de parar la animación, debes parar el setinterval, con un clearInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero guardar el evento de `setInterval` y  limpiarlo cuando para la animación, de lo contrario se seguirá ejecutando. También no sé porque asignas dos eventos de click de manera separada, podrías hacerlo en el mismo.

Puedes utilizar la misma variable que guarda la referencia del `setInterval` para ver si la animación está corriendo o no.

Cómo dice [Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby) es mejor sacar la función del evento, de lo contrario estamos creando una nueva instancia con cada click del usuario.

```js
let refInterval = null;

function empezarAnimacion() {
  $("#divTarget").animate({
      left: "+=200px"
    }, 2000)
    .animate({
      left: "-=200px"
    }, 2000);
}

$("#movContinuo").click(function() {
  if (refInterval) {
    $("#divTarget").stop(true);
    clearInterval(refInterval);
    refInterval = null;
  } else {
    refInterval = setInterval(empezarAnimacion, 2000);
  }
});
```

```css
#divTarget {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divTarget">
</div>
<button id="movContinuo">
Mover
</button>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta; solo sacaría la función `empezarAnimacion()` de ahí, porque se estaría creando cada vez que se activa la animación.

Comment: ¡Tienes toda la razón! Ya lo cambio.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a los dos! funciona perfectamente, ahora ya veo por que me repetía la animación.